# How to copy a "double pointer"?

Tags: c, loops, pointers, copy

I'm a novice in C. I have a function with such a structure (this code is not reproducible, this is "pseudo-code", but I hope it's enough to explain my problem):

```
unsigned** myfunction(double*** A, unsigned nx, unsigned ny, unsigned nz){
    unsigned* cells[nz-1];
    unsigned totallength = 0;
    unsigned lengths[nz-1];
    unsigned** bottomTypes = function1(A, nx, ny, 0);
    for(unsigned k=0; k<nz-1; k++){
        unsigned** topTypes = function1(A, nx, ny, k+1);
        unsigned** cellTypes = function2(bottomTypes, topTypes);
        unsigned length
        unsigned** goodcells = function3(cellTypes, &length);
        cells[k] = malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned));
        for(unsigned l=0; l<length; l++){
            cells[k][l] = goodcells[0][l] + k;
        }
        lengths[k] = length;
        totallength += length;
        bottomTypes = function1(A, nx, ny, k+1); // the same as topTypes
    }
    unsigned** out = malloc(4 * sizeof(unsigned*));
    ......
    ......
    return out;
}
```

As you can see, at the end of the loop, I do `bottomTypes = function1(A, nx, ny, k+1);` which is the same as `topTypes` previousy introduced. Thus `function1(A,nx,ny,k+1)` is called twice. That's because I've not been able to copy `topTypes` in `bottomTypes`. The code produced the expected output when I do like this.

Instead of doing like this, to avoid the doube call, I've tried

```
**bottomTypes = **topTypes;
```

or

```
bottomTypes = malloc((nx-1) * sizeof(unsigned*));
for ( int i = 0; i < nx-1; ++i ){
    bottomTypes[i] = malloc((ny-1)*sizeof(unsigned));
    memcpy(bottomTypes[i], topTypes[i], ny-1);
}
```

The code compiles but I don't get the expected resut when I do that.

What is the right way to copy `topTypes` into `bottomTypes` ?

I hope this is clear. Otherwise do not hesitate to say me it's not clear and I'll try to make a reproducibe exampe, but it's not easy. I've found similar questions on SO but none of them allows me to solve my issue.

## Edit

Below is a complete reproducibe example. Not very minimal, I admit.

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf

// function to create a "three-dimensional array" (I know this is not the correct wording)
//  from a given function
double*** fun2array(double f(unsigned,unsigned,unsigned), unsigned nx, unsigned ny, unsigned nz){
    double*** out = (double***) malloc(nx * sizeof(double**));
    for(unsigned i=0; i<nx; i++){
        out[i] = (double**) malloc(ny * sizeof(double*));
        for(unsigned j=0; j<ny; j++){
            out[i][j] = (double*) malloc(nz * sizeof(double));
            for(unsigned k=0; k<nz; k++){
                out[i][j][k] = f(i,j,k);
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}

// a three-dimensional array
double fun(unsigned i, unsigned j, unsigned k){
    return i+j+k;
}
double*** A = fun2array(fun, 2, 3, 4);

// function to "slice" a 3d-array to a 2D-array (a "matrix")
double** toMatrix(double*** A, unsigned nx, unsigned ny, unsigned k){
    double** out = (double**) malloc(nx * sizeof(double*));
    for(unsigned i=0; i<nx; i++){
        out[i] = (double*) malloc(ny * sizeof(double));
        for(unsigned j=0; j<ny; j++){
            out[i][j] = A[i][j][k];
        }
    }
    return out;    
}

// function to convert double matrix to integer matrix
unsigned** floorMatrix(double** M , unsigned nx, unsigned ny){
    unsigned** out = (unsigned**) malloc(nx * sizeof(unsigned*));
    for(unsigned i=0; i<nx; i++){
        out[i] = (unsigned*) malloc(ny * sizeof(unsigned));
        for(unsigned j=0; j<ny; j++){
            out[i][j] = (unsigned) M[i][j];
        }
    }
    return out;
}

// function to sum 2 "matrices"
unsigned** matricialSum(unsigned** M1, unsigned** M2, unsigned nx, unsigned ny){
    unsigned** out = (unsigned**) malloc(nx * sizeof(unsigned*));
    for(unsigned i=0; i<nx; i++){
        out[i] = (unsigned*) malloc(ny * sizeof(unsigned));
        for(unsigned j=0; j<ny; j++){
            out[i][j] = M1[i][j] + M2[i][j];
        }
    }
    return out;
}

unsigned myfunction(double*** A, unsigned nx, unsigned ny, unsigned nz){
    unsigned** bottomTypes = floorMatrix(toMatrix(A, nx, ny, 0), nx, ny);
    unsigned** cellTypes;
    for(unsigned k=0; k<nz-1; k++){
        unsigned** topTypes = floorMatrix(toMatrix(A, nx, ny, k+1), nx, ny);
        cellTypes = matricialSum(bottomTypes, topTypes, nx, ny);
        bottomTypes = floorMatrix(toMatrix(A, nx, ny, k+1), nx, ny); // the same as topTypes
    }
    return cellTypes[0][0];
}


int main(){
    unsigned result = myfunction(A, 2, 3, 4);
    printf("result:%u\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

## 2nd edit

I have a solution, but surey not optimal:

```
unsigned** copyMatrix(unsigned** M, unsigned nx, unsigned ny){
    unsigned** MM = malloc(nx * sizeof(unsigned*));
    for(unsigned i=0; i<nx; i++){
        MM[i] = malloc(ny * sizeof(unsigned));
        for(unsigned j=0; j<ny; j++){
            MM[i][j] = M[i][j];
        }
    }
    return MM;
}
```

Then in the example code I free `bottomTypes` and then I do

```
unsigned** bottomTypes = copyMatrix(topTypes, nx-1, ny-1);
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb: whenever you have more than 2 levels of indirection in a C program, your design has gone bad. This is called "three star programming" and is a sarcasm for code that is needlessly complex. Perhaps you meant to use [proper multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) instead?

Comment: Excuse-me @Stargateur, what is "NANI" ? `A***` is a three-dimensional array.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Lundin, but this sounds too complex for me, sorry. I'm really novice in C. I even don't see what you mean by "2 levels of indirection".

Comment: http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer, it's simple as the number of `*` your variable have, basically, you have a pointer of pointer of pointer of double... that clearly something that should never happen in C. We can't help you a lot cause you didn't give a [mcve] or the context of your code. I clearly see that your data structure could be improve a lot but without have detail we can't help you.

Comment: *pointer = 1 level of indirection, **pointer = 2 levels. And so on. `A***` is _not_ a three-dimensional array. Using three dimensional arrays is much easier than obscure three star programming. Just one malloc, one free.

Comment: And yeah I think you need to clarify this with a minimal example, because the whole program design seems bad from the start and could likely be rewritten in much simpler and faster ways.

Comment: @Lundin Ok, I will try. But it will take me a certain time. Please guys wait for my edit before downvoting ;-)

Comment: bottomTypes = topTypes ??

Comment: @Lundin Done. I've added a complete example (which has nothing to do with my real exampe, I tried to make something minimal).

Comment: @purec Yes, both are `function1(A, nx, ny, k+1)`. But then `topTypes` is updated at the next step of the loop.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Well, this isn't valid C. You can't initialize a global variable like `double*** A = fun2array(fun, 2, 3, 4);`.

Comment: @Lundin ok (however the code works) Can I put `double*** A = fun2array(fun, 2, 3, 4);` in `main` then ?

Comment: floorMatrix() does it's job. I think there is no easier way.

Comment: I don't understand why you need 3D matrix, sorry these maths are out of my league, I can see a lot of way, to produce better code, but like You didn't provide context of how this code is suppose to be use, I can't help you without be sure to break the code. However here a better readable code version,  http://rextester.com/LUOMOF9870.

Comment: @Stargateur This is for the *marching cubes algorithm* A function must be evaluated at each vertex of a 3D-grid. Thanks for the link, I will take a look.

Comment: I would recommend you switch to a linear array representation for the matrices, similar to what I outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862940/1475978). In your case, instead of `rows`, `cols`, `rowstride`, and `colstride`, you'd have for example `nx`, `ny`, `nz`, `xstride`, `ystride` and `zstride`. Element `(x, y, z)` of `m` is then at `m->origin[x*m->xstride + y*m->ystride + z*m->zstride]`. Its power is in the flexibility it allows in managing the matrices, including matrices that are "views" (transposed and/or partial) to other matrices.

Answer (score 2):

I finally understand your question, you write `**bottomTypes = **topTypes;` in place of `bottomTypes = topTypes;`. This is simply replace pointer by another.

However there are a lot of potential issue with your code, you have memory leak, you use [ThreeStar](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer), you cast return of malloc, etc. If your purpose to use C is to be fast, I advice you to change your data structure. `malloc()` is expensive and unless you want to be able to swap two lines of your matrix with `O(1)`, there are no need to have one malloc for every lines of yours matrix.

So:

- [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- You could use [FAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) if you don't want too many `malloc()`
- You have memory leak each time you drop `topTypes` and `bottomTypes` or `cellTypes`, I suppose it only in your [mcve].
- In your orignal code you use [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), this should be use carefully.
- You use unsigned instead of `size_t` for index, not a big problem if you don't use very big matrix.

Your [mcve] with little fix, memory leak everywhere:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf

// function to create a "three-dimensional array" (I know this is not the
// correct wording)
//  from a given function
double ***fun2array(double (*f)(size_t, size_t, size_t), size_t nx, size_t ny,
                    size_t nz) {
  double ***out = malloc(nx * sizeof *out);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    out[i] = malloc(ny * sizeof *out[i]);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
      out[i][j] = malloc(nz * sizeof *out[i][j]);
      for (size_t k = 0; k < nz; k++) {
        out[i][j][k] = f(i, j, k);
      }
    }
  }
  return out;
}

// a three-dimensional array
double fun(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) { return i + j + k; }

// function to "slice" a 3d-array to a 2D-array (a "matrix")
double **toMatrix(double ***A, size_t nx, size_t ny, size_t k) {
  double **out = malloc(nx * sizeof *out);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    out[i] = malloc(ny * sizeof *out[i]);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
      out[i][j] = A[i][j][k];
    }
  }
  return out;
}

// function to convert double matrix to integer matrix
unsigned **floorMatrix(double **M, size_t nx, size_t ny) {
  unsigned **out = malloc(nx * sizeof *out);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    out[i] = malloc(ny * sizeof *out[i]);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
      out[i][j] = M[i][j];
    }
  }
  return out;
}

// function to sum 2 "matrices"
unsigned **matricialSum(unsigned **M1, unsigned **M2, size_t nx, size_t ny) {
  unsigned **out = malloc(nx * sizeof *out);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
    out[i] = malloc(ny * sizeof *out[i]);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
      out[i][j] = M1[i][j] + M2[i][j];
    }
  }
  return out;
}

unsigned myfunction(double ***A, size_t nx, size_t ny, size_t nz) {
  unsigned **bottomTypes = floorMatrix(toMatrix(A, nx, ny, 0), nx, ny);
  unsigned **cellTypes = bottomTypes;
  for (size_t k = 1; k < nz; k++) {
    unsigned **topTypes = floorMatrix(toMatrix(A, nx, ny, k), nx, ny);
    cellTypes = matricialSum(bottomTypes, topTypes, nx, ny);
    bottomTypes = topTypes;
  }
  return cellTypes[0][0];
}

int main(void) {
  double ***A = fun2array(fun, 2, 3, 4);
  unsigned result = myfunction(A, 2, 3, 4);
  printf("result:%u\n", result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will study all that carefully. So I can simpy do `bottomTypes = topTypes` ? That's weird, I was sure I tried that and there was an issue. But maybe I did something else wrong. Thanks again !