# Allocate and free memory in the loop (C + MPI)

Tags: c, pointers, mpi, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

Please see my following code snippet (floatalloc2 is for allocating a 2D contiguous array with datatype float, see Appendix if interested):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
float **p=NULL, **buffer=NULL;
int it, nt=3, i, j, k, NP, MYID, nx=1, nz=2, nsrc=3, isrc;

MPI_Init ( &argc, &argv );
MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &NP );
MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MYID ); 

p = floatalloc2(nx,nz);
memset(p[0],0,nz*nx*sizeof(float));

for (it=0; it<nt; it++){            
    for (isrc=MYID; isrc<nsrc; isrc+=NP){
        for (j=0; j<nz; j++){
            for (i=0; i<nx; i++){
                p[j][i] += 1.5 + (float)(isrc) + (float)(j);                   
            }
        }

    }

    for (k=0;k<nsrc-1;k++){ 
        if (MYID==k){ 
            buffer = floatalloc2(nx,nz); 
            memset(buffer[0],0,nz*nx*sizeof(float));
            buffer = p;   

        }else{                
            buffer = floatalloc2(nx,nz);
            memset(buffer[0],0,nz*nx*sizeof(float));
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&buffer[0][0],nx*nz,MPI_FLOAT,k,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        for (j=0; j<nz; j++){
            for (i=0; i<nx; i++){
                printf("it=%d,k=%d,Node %d,p[%d][%d]=%f\n",it,k,MYID,j,i,p[j][i]);
            }
        }                        
        free(*buffer);free(buffer); /*w/o this line is ok while not ok with this line */
    }

}

MPI_Finalize();
exit(0);
}
```

As a thumb of rule, C frees memory once it was allocated, even in the loop. But here, if I don't add `free(*buffer);free(buffer);`, it's quite good. However, if with the `free`, the results are wrong. So what's wrong in my code?

Appendix for floatalloc2:

```
/*@out@*/ void *sf_alloc (size_t n, size_t size )
  /*< output-checking allocation >*/
{
void *ptr; 

size *= n;

if (0>=size) sf_error("%s: illegal allocation (%d bytes)",__FILE__,size);

ptr = malloc (size);

if (NULL == ptr)
sf_error ("%s: cannot allocate %lu bytes:", __FILE__,size);

return ptr;
}


/*@out@*/ float *sf_floatalloc (size_t n)
  /*< float allocation >*/ 
{
float *ptr;
ptr = (float*) sf_alloc (n,sizeof(float));
return ptr;
}


/*@out@*/ float **floatalloc2 (size_t n1 , size_t n2 )
/*< float 2-D allocation, out[0] points to a contiguous array >*/ 
{
  size_t i2;
  float **ptr;

  ptr = (float**) sf_alloc (n2,sizeof(float*));
  ptr[0] = sf_floatalloc (n1*n2);
  for (i2=1; i2 < n2; i2++) {
    ptr[i2] = ptr[0]+i2*n1;
  }
  return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the library that provides `floatalloc2` not provide something like `floatunalloc2`? Most likely your `free` calls are not in correspondence with the memory allocations.

Comment: @Bathsheba I've added an appendix for `floatalloc2`

Comment: There *must* be a library function to `free` this for you. Even if you manage to replicate that, there's no guarantee it will work in subsequent versions of whatever library you're using.

Comment: Since you are using MPI, you are probably interested in high-performance computing. In that case, you should know that double indirection (`float **p`, i.e. `p[row][column]` referring to an element, with `p` and `p[row]` being pointers) is much slower than using a linear array with index arithmetic, i.e. `float *all;` with `all[row*columns + column]` referring to an element, on current architectures. This means that this approach will never be as efficient as a linear array would be.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks for your comment. At current stage my goal is to get the code run correctly. I'll think about efficiency at next stage.

Comment: After allocation, why re-assign `buffer` in `buffer = floatalloc2(nx,nz); 
...
            buffer = p;`?  Looks like a memory leak.

Comment: @chux so you mean after `**buffer=NULL`, I can directly assign `buffer = p` without allocating memory?

Comment: coco, "after `**buffer=NULL`" is unclear as that code is not in the post.  Further that [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788667/allocate-and-free-memory-in-the-loop-c-mpi?noredirect=1#comment90536089_51788667) is not directly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788667/allocate-and-free-memory-in-the-loop-c-mpi?noredirect=1#comment90535253_51788667)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say we use `float **p = floatalloc2(columns, rows)`. Then, `p` is allocated for `rows` float pointers (`float *`), and `p[0]` for `columns*rows` floats. If the library does not provide a `floatfree2()` or `free2()` function, you can free the memory allocated for the 2D array using `free(*p); free(p);`, in that order. This is what OP is doing, too.

The inner loop,

> ```
>     for (k=0;k<nsrc-1;k++){ 
>         if (MYID==k){ 
>             buffer = floatalloc2(nx,nz); 
>             memset(buffer[0],0,nz*nx*sizeof(float));
>             buffer = p;
>         }else{                
>             buffer = floatalloc2(nx,nz);
>             memset(buffer[0],0,nz*nx*sizeof(float));
>         }
>         ...
>         free(*buffer);free(buffer); /*w/o this line is ok while not ok with this line */
>     }
> ```

The `buffer = p;` line replaces the 2D array allocated and initialized on the preceding two lines; this is essentially a memory leak.  I suppose the idea was to *copy* the contents of the `p` to it, but I cannot be sure.

Furthermore, later on, the `free(*buffer); free(buffer);` line ends up freeing the 2D array described by `p` on the `k == MYID` iteration.

One approach to solve this is to let `buffer` alias `p` when `k == MYID`:

```
 for (k = 0; k < nsrc-1; k++) { 
    if (MYID == k) {
        buffer = p;
    } else {                
        buffer = floatalloc2(nx,nz);
        memset(buffer[0], 0, nz*nx*sizeof(float));
    }
    ...
    if (buffer != p) {
        free(*buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }
}
```

This way, when `k == MYID`, `buffer` actually points to `p`; otherwise it is dynamically allocated and freed for each iteration. Obviously, when `buffer` aliases `p`, we do not free it, because that would free `p`.

You could add `free(*p); free(p);` just before `MPI_Finalize()`, to free the memory allocated for `p` too, but it isn't strictly necessary because the process is about to exit anyway. (It is useful, however, if you use e.g. Valgrind to look for memory leaks, or wish to show that you (the programmer) do track dynamic allocations correctly; in that case, adding a comment there is probably useful.)

A much better approach is to allocate the buffer only once, and then reuse it for each iteration:

```
float **p, **buffer;

p = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
memset(p[0], 0, nz*nx*sizeof p[0][0]);

buffer = floatalloc2(nx, nz);
memset(buffer[0], 0, nz*nx*sizeof buffer[0][0]);

for (it=0; it < nt; it++) {
    for (isrc=MYID; isrc < nsrc; isrc+=NP) {
        for (j=0; j<nz; j++){
            for (i=0; i<nx; i++){
                p[j][i] += 1.5 + (float)(isrc) + (float)(j);                   
            }
        }
    }

    for (k=0; k<nsrc-1; k++) {
        float **data;

        if (MYID == k) {
            data = p;
        } else {
            data = buffer;
            memset(buffer[0], 0, nz*nx*sizeof buffer[0][0]);
        }

        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&(data[0][0]), nx*nz, MPI_FLOAT, k, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        for (j=0; j<nz; j++) {
            for (i=0; i<nx; i++) {
                printf("it=%d,k=%d,Node %d,data[%d][%d]=%f, p[%d][%d]=%f\n",
                       it, k, MYID, j, i, data[j][i], p[j][i]);
            }
        }                        
    }
}

free(*buffer);
free(buffer);

free(*p);
free(p);
```

Note that the `sizeof p[0][0]` and `sizeof buffer[0][0]` are statements that evaluate to the size (in chars) of each element of `p`/`buffer`, and *do not* actually examine any memory. Those are allowed, and safe, even if `p == NULL` or `p[0] == NULL`, because the compiler simply examines the *type* of the expression (to the right of the `sizeof` operator). To remind myself of that, I never use parentheses around the variable reference on the right of the `sizeof` operator. (When you use a type, like `float`, the parentheses are required. Then, I write it as `sizeof (float)`.)  This helps me remember that `sizeof` is an operator, and does not behave like a function, although it may look like a function.

The `float **data;` is just a reference (or alias) to the actual data in `p` or `buffer`; all we need to use it is to assign it, either `data = p;` or `data = buffer;`.  Because it is a reference or alias, pointing to exactly the same data, we do not `free()` it at all. If we did, we'd just end up freeing the original data, `p` or `buffer`.

---

In a comment to the question, I mentioned that using double indirection (`float **data`, where `data[row][column]` is an element, and both `data[row]` and `data` are pointers) is not very efficient.  In practice, a structure is used instead. For example:

```
typedef struct {
    int    rows;
    int    cols;
    float *data;
} float2d;
#define  FLOAT2D_INIT  { 0, 0, NULL }

static inline void float2d_alloc(float2d *m, const int rows, const int cols)
{
    do {
        if (!m) {
            fprintf(stderr, "float2d_alloc(): No matrix specified.\n");
            break;
        }

        if (rows < 1 || cols < 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "float2d_alloc(): Invalid matrix size (%d rows, %d cols).\n", rows, cols);
            break;
        }

        m->data = malloc((size_t)rows * (size_t)cols * sizeof m->data[0]);
        if (!m->data) {
            fprintf(stderr, "float2d_alloc(): Not enough memory available.\n");
            break;
        }

        m->rows = rows;
        m->cols = cols;
        return;

    } while (0);

    /* MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1); */
    exit(1);
}

static inline void float2d_free(float2d *m)
{
    if (m) {
        free(m->data);
        m->rows = 0;
        m->cols = 0;
        m->data = NULL;
    }
}
```

If you have `float2d p;` allocated, then to access the element on row `r`, column `c`, you use `p.data[r*p.cols + c]`. All the data is consecutive in memory; there being `p.cols*p.rows` elements, with total size being `p.cols*p.rows*sizeof p.data[0]`.  To refer to the array of floats on row `r`, you can use `p.data + r*p.rows` (which is equivalent to `&(p.data[r*p.rows])`).

If you are interested in this approach, and work a lot with matrices (or dense 2D arrays of data), you might wish to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862940/1475978) for an example of structures that takes this a step further. It basically allows one to create realtime views (references to the exact same data) to any regular rectangular part (can be e.g. diagonal, a submatrix, some consecutive odd rows, even rows, etc.) of another matrix, with the code keeping tabs (counting references to) the data, so that when you destroy a matrix that was the final user of some data, the data gets freed automatically.  Each element access does require two multiplications and one addition instead of just one multiplication and one addition, but it turns out to be neglible overhead in practice, and the versatility of the matrix structures definitely balances that out.

Comment: Very Excellent  and detailed answer. As you said, `A much better approach is to allocate the buffer only once, and then reuse it for each iteration`. I found that if I allocate the buffer only once, and in the for loop, I use `for (j=0; j<nz; j++){
                    for (i=0; i<nx; i++){
                        buffer[j][i] = p[j][i];  
                    }
                } ` (so called deep copy) can also get the expected results without freeing `buffer`

Comment: "I suppose the idea was to copy the contents of the p to it, but I cannot be sure." Yes, exactly, you're right.

Comment: I read your answer word by word. It's really great answer and I love it. Thanks.

Comment: But I have a small question, you defined the alias `float **data` in the code body. Can we do this? Because I was taught variables are defined in the very beginning of the code.

Comment: @coco: Yes. Even in C89, you can declare variables at the start of each block (`{ ... }`).

Answer (score 2):

A different approach is to use VLAs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_matrix(int nx, int ny, int a[nx][ny])
{
    printf("Printing matrix at %p\n", &a[0][0]);
    for (int i=0; i < nx; i++) {
        printf("%d", a[i][0]);
        for (int j=1; j < ny; j++)
            printf(", %d", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nx = 3, nz = 2;

    /* two different syntaxes */
    int (*A)[nx][nz] = malloc(sizeof(int[nx][nz]));
    int (*B)[nz] = malloc(sizeof(int[nx][nz]));

    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
        for (int k = 0; k < nz; k++) {
            (*A)[i][k] = (i+1)*(k+1);
            B[i][k] = (i+1)*(k+1);
        }
    print_matrix(nx, nz, *A);
    print_matrix(nx, nz, B);

    free(A);
    free(B);
}
```

I strongly recommend the free book "Modern C" available here: https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/modern-c-is-now-feature-complete/

Comment: Tip: `int (*A)[nx][nz] = malloc(sizeof(int[nx][nz]));` may be simplified to `int (*A)[nx][nz] = malloc(sizeof *A);` and `int (*B)[nz] = malloc(sizeof *B * nx);`

Comment: @chux, thanks for highlighting that.  I go back and forth on which syntax I prefer.