# How to make the program see the new matrix I created?

Tags: c

I want to realize the matrix multiplication using Strassen method. Since my input matrix will not be `2^n *2^n` all the time, for example, it could be 3*3 matrix, I need to fill the edge area with 0. But I came across a problem when I create new matrix `A_new[][]` for `A[][]`, `B_new[][]` for `B[][]`. I can successfully generate the `A_new[][]` and `B_new[][]` for both square(2*2, etc.) or (3*3,etc.). But when I want to further use `A_new[][]` and `B_new[][]`, which I created before, the code outside the "if" statement couldn't see it.

Is there some ways that I could make the code which is outside the "if" statement see it and process it?

Here are my code.

```
void strassen(int A[][N], int B[][N], int C[][N]) {
  if (N == 1) {
    C[0][0] = A[0][0] * B[0][0];
  }

  if (N > 1 && N % 2 != 0) {
    int A_new[N + 1][N + 1];
    int B_new[N + 1][N + 1];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N + 1; i++) {
      if (i == N) {
        for (j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
          A_new[i][j] = 0;
          B_new[i][j] = 0;
        }

      } else {
        for (j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
          if (j == N) {
            A_new[i][j] = 0;
            B_new[i][j] = 0;
          } else {
            A_new[i][j] = A[i][j];
            B_new[i][j] = B[i][j];

          }

        }
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N + 1; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
        C[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }

  } else {
    int i, j;
    int A_new[N][N];
    int B_new[N][N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        A_new[i][j] = A[i][j];
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        B_new[i][j] = B[i][j];
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        C[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: take them out of the if scope and move it to the upper scope. if(...){if scope}. vars are local to the scope they are declared in. so if you move their declarations prior to the first if statement they will be "alive" for all of the functions scope and not only in the if scope

Comment: I can't because outside the if statement, I am not sure about the matrix size, and if it  can be divide by 2, the size will be N, if it can't, the size would be N+1.

Comment: you can define pointers ,and allocate memory on the heap using malloc.

Comment: by the way, you can "waist" memory and make them N+1 anyways. and if the size needs to be N, just use your inner mat.

Comment: I suspect the 1`}

  if (N > 1 && N % 2 != 0) {` should be `}  else if (N > 1 && N % 2 != 0) {`.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to C , so I was trying to avoid the pointer and memory allocation to realize the function, but could you give me some source or example that I could read. BTW, is that means to realize the strassen method, we must use the pointer?

Comment: @chux I think the same an else if missing

Comment: Your answer is more formal, but it's not the key issue here I think

Comment: The problem you have here is where you allocate the memory.  what I suggested and suggested in the answer below is to allocate N+1 matrix either way. if you do so- you don't HAVE to use all of it if you only need an N mat.

Comment: If one starts by implementing a matrix structure [along the lines here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856555/how-to-work-on-a-sub-matrix-in-a-matrix-by-pointer), with views to existing matrices being first-class citizens, the implementation becomes much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

if you move `int A_new[N + 1][N + 1];` and `int B_new[N + 1][N + 1];` before the if you can use *A* and *B* in the two branches of the *if* without problem, and they are available after the *if* too of course. You do not use all the cells in the *else* branch but that has no consequences

```
  int A_new[N + 1][N + 1];
  int B_new[N + 1][N + 1];

  if (N > 1 && N % 2 != 0) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N + 1; i++) {
      if (i == N) {
        for (j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
          A_new[i][j] = 0;
          B_new[i][j] = 0;
        }

      } else {
        for (j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
          if (j == N) {
            A_new[i][j] = 0;
            B_new[i][j] = 0;
          } else {
            A_new[i][j] = A[i][j];
            B_new[i][j] = B[i][j];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N + 1; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
        C[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }

  } else {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        A_new[i][j] = A[i][j];
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        B_new[i][j] = B[i][j];
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        C[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

As chux says in a remark you missed an else (or you just *return* if *N == 1* ?) and the code can be

```
  int A_new[N + 1][N + 1];
  int B_new[N + 1][N + 1];

  if (N == 1) {
    C[0][0] = A[0][0] * B[0][0];
  }
  else if (N > 1 && N % 2 != 0) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N + 1; i++) {
      if (i == N) {
        for (j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
          A_new[i][j] = 0;
          B_new[i][j] = 0;
        }

      } else {
        for (j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
          if (j == N) {
            A_new[i][j] = 0;
            B_new[i][j] = 0;
          } else {
            A_new[i][j] = A[i][j];
            B_new[i][j] = B[i][j];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N + 1; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N + 1; j++) {
        C[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }

  } else {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        A_new[i][j] = A[i][j];
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        B_new[i][j] = B[i][j];
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        C[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I can't because outside the if statement, I am not sure about the matrix size, and if it can be divide by 2, the size will be N, if it can't, the size would be N+1

Comment: @SHANGZHOU while the matrix is enough large for all the cases there are no problem, just some cells will not be used, that all, that cannot be a problem